# Displaying PDF from Memory Stream to browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, itext

I am trying to display a pdf created dynamically and display it in the browser, but I am getting the below characters( a whole lot of them)

Im using iTextSharp

> \�(l�x�)�(�)���g���29��2�`C�B�Wa���[�(�o��x��3�J  :k��v�os�R

The code which I used to create the pdf does work when sending it by email as an attachment.

Maybe im wrong on displaying it ?

```
        ....
        doc.Close();

        Response.Clear();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=labtest.pdf");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        stream2.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();
```

code above is in a controller method

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `Write` and `WriteTo` methods are aware of the current `Position` and take that into account. Can you try changing your code around to `Response.BinaryWrite(stream2.ToArray())`

Comment: Also, you're not trying to do this with AJAX, are you?

Comment: I have found another solution, by first saving the file, and then open it. Yes I was doing it with AJAX, why ?

Comment: AJAX in its general form is text-based which is why you are seeing a text-representation of a PDF. You need to switch to binary processing if you want to work with binary data but that's a whole different question. See this for an intro http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments of question.
Credit to Chris Haas

> AJAX in its general form is text-based which is why you are seeing a
>   text-representation of a PDF. You need to switch to binary processing
>   if you want to work with binary data but that's a whole different
>   question. See this for an intro html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2